# Should a SQL database be able to handle the creation of thousands of tables on a daily basis or do I have to change my code?

Tags: sql, database-design

This is my first time designing tables in a sql database and I have no idea how much server cpu this would use and whether this is a viable way of coding.

I have to create a bidding site where the gist is every time someone bids (where bids have to be bought separately at 50 cents per bid) the final price goes up by 1 cent, 2 cents, or 5 cents.

The trouble I'm facing is that I have to make a database table to keep track of the item's bid history and it seems like I have to create an individual table for each item (3 things need to be kept track of apart from the item id - bidder, bit time, cents at which it was bid on).

I'm fairly inexperienced in this and am willing to go back to the drawing board to brainstorm another table design, but was wondering if creating thousands (assuming the site will be somewhat successful) of table on a daily basis for each new item being listed is something that's alright. And I'm probably overestimating site traffic and might be more in the range of just a few hundred tables per day, but I want to prepare for the worst.

Comment: my client wants me to build a site like quibids.com

Comment: A design where you add tables like that is nearly always bad. Why do you need a separate table for the history? Just add a `bid_id` column to you bid history table and don't create a new one for each bid.

Comment: What is preventing you from having a table which holds each individual auction where they have their own unique Id, and then a single table to hold bids which referents the Auction table through that unique Id? You do not need to create new tables each time.

Comment: I was under the impression that each table cell shouldn't have too much information. So basically what you guys are saying is I should just continuously add to the individual, relevant table cell each time I need an update for a particular item? If I create a column like bid_time, it would have to contain between 5 and 100 separate bid times in it, is this the better way to go?

Comment: that's the concept of a database... you have n columns in a table (like bid time, itemid...) and several rows in that table, each rows holding values for each column in that tabel... then you can have several tables which rows that can even referance rows in the same or other table (google for normalization, primary key, foreign key...)

Comment: oic, now I understand what Mat was saying. So basically, just create a bid_id column that records the id for each new bid so that even if the bit times for one specific item is all over the place in the table, it can still be found and referenced through the bid_id column. Did I get that right?

Comment: I think you need more help than you can expect in this forum. If you haven't designed databases before then hire someone to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go back to the drawing board. Creating new tables for what is essentially the same thing is poor design. Have you heard of the DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) principle.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think you need one table per item ?

you could design a table structure with perhaps to hold your items, their bid history with 2-3 tables for all items together... depending on the metadata it could usefull to have another 1-2 tables... always NOT pet item but per "information type" (like "item history", "item metadata").